# Why is Cyanidine soluble in water?

Tags: organic-chemistry, solubility, polarity

Cyanidine is not polar due to its make-up of only hydrogen atoms and carbon atoms, correct? But "like dissolve like", which means it would HAVE to be polar, or no? Is it then soluble solely because of its OH-groups being able to create hydrogen bonds with the water molecules, thereby making it miscible?

[image]

Comment: And what is it this "polarity" your asking about? I wonder if you know what you're talking about.

Comment: Well, I read it was soluble in water. It'd have to be polar, then? @Mithoron

Comment: Then ask why it is soluble in water...

Comment: @Mithoron Good point. I'll edit.

Comment: The very word "polar" seems to be confusing; it has two altogether different meanings.

Comment: @IvanNeretin how so?

Comment: One meaning is "_a molecule which has a lot of highly polar bonds and hence is soluble in water and stuff_"; another is "_a molecule which has zero dipole moment_". These are by no means equivalent.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Well, I'm referring to the first meaning in this case.

Comment: Then your molecule is highly polar and should be soluble in water.

Comment: But the OH-groups are scattered around, wouldn't that affect the polarity of the molecule as a whole in a negative way? @IvanNeretin

Comment: You say cyanidine is not polar due to being made only of hydrogen and carbon, but then talk about it having OH groups. It has oxygen. Not only that but it is a charged species (also clearly shown on your structure). So that is two reasons why your initial suspicion of non-polarity because it is s simple hydrocarbon are wrong.

Comment: @matt_black Fair point. The oxygen ion has a positive charge, how does this differ from the negative charge in terms of electronegativity? Is it then weaker than an oxygen atom?

Comment: @Mithoron Also, I suppose the molecule is asymmetrical as well, making it polar along with the OH-groups?

Comment: Don't mention this dipole idiocy, it's irrelevant for solubility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cyanidine actually looks to me to be a rather highly polar compound. It's essentially a $\ce{C15}$ hydrocarbon having 5 hydroxyl groups and a formal positive charge.

The ratio of hydroxyl groups to the number of carbons is the same as that of water-miscible isopropyl alcohol. (Of course smaller molecules like isopropyl alcohol also tend to be more soluble than larger molecules.)

The most important feature indicative of it's rather high polarity and water solubility is it's formal positive charge. This is analogous to placing a positive charge on a large amine by protination in order to turn the amine into a polar, water soluble compound.

Comment: So the positive charge makes it polar? I suppose it is irrelevant that it is placed practically in the middle of the molecule?

Comment: Yes and yes. Usually when we talk about a molecule being polar, we're talking about regions of somewhat higher and lower electron density due to inductive or other effects. We usually call this "delta +" or "delta -" indicating a partial charge. These partial charges, or regions of higher or lower electron density, are far less pronounced than the case of having a full formal charge. The location of the charge can make some difference if it's very sterically "hidden", but that's not the case here.